# render objects in specific position with parametrize in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, position

so i want to create an object, a message boxes that will be rendered on the screen in a relative position in the container.
i know to use position: 'relative' or 'absolute' and use the top and left values, but i want in addition to get the specific coordinates from the container component. 
each instance of message box i want to render in a specific location retrieved from the container.
in general i cant find something in react native that fit my needs... im trying to make an app with managing objects on the screen in absolute position, all the algorithm where to render and how to move will be managed by me, but i cant find a good way to do that in react native seems like all the styles are better suit for relative and rendering obejcts by order design, someone has any tips?

```
enter code here:
    export default class Message extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        };

        render() {
            var position = StyleSheet.create({top: this.props.top, 
                                              left: this.props.left});
            var absoluteCircle = StyleSheet.flatten([styles.circle, 
                                                     position]);

            return (
                <View style={absoluteCircle}>
                     <Text style={styles.circleText}>{this.props.bubbleText} 
                     </Text>
                </View>
            );
      }
    }
```